# iOS - Long Press Gesture Recognizer for UIButton in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UITableViewCell` with 3 `UIButton`s in it used to decrement a counter. On long press one of the buttons, I would like to set the counter to 0.

Doing this in Interface Builder, I dragged a `Long Press Gesture Recognizer` onto my `button` and connected the selector to an `IBAction` specified in my `UITableViewCell.m`.

That's all I did but when I run the app it gives the following error.

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'invalid nib registered for identifier (editQuotaCell) 
- nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UITableViewCell instance'
```

Am I missing any steps?

Comment: post your cellforrowatindex code. If possible take a screenshot of your EditQuotaCell xib and post it here. The answer for your question may be anywer(xib or code)

Answer (score -1):

Just create the button in coding wise add the gesture and selector. It will work. Check the bellow code

```
 -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
     if(cell == nil)
     {
         UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
         cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
         cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

         UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
         [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(select_Action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         [btn setTag:Selection_Tag];
         [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Demo03.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,tableView.frame.size.width,tableView.rowHeight)];
         [cell.contentView btn];

        //Add Your gestures here
     }


     return cell;
 }
```